# Codeigniter: search gender male or female from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website where I need to add a search option by gender.

If user clicks on male gender option then it must show all male gender's from database and their related info.

Same goes for the female gender option.

I have the code but its not working properly.

Here is the code

In model when I do

```
$this->db->where('gender');
```

It gives me output but when I use

```
$this->db->where('gender'='male');
```

It shows me blank page

controller

```
        function searchmale()
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true)
            {
                $this->load->view('searchmalegender');
            }
            else
                $this->index();
        }

        function searchmaleconfirm()
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true)
            {

                $data['freemembers'] = $this->freemember_model->searchmale();
            //  $data['domesticmembers'] = $this->domesticmember_model->searchmale();
                //$data['overseasmembers'] = $this->overseasmember_model->search($search);
                //$data['messages'] = $this->messageboard_model->getallmessages();

                $sessiondata = array();
                $sessiondata = $this->session->all_userdata();
                $this->load->view('maleresult',$data);

            }
            else
                $this->index();
```

Model.php

```
    function searchmale(){
    $this->db->from('free_members');        
            $this->db->where('gender'= 'male');
            //$this->db->order_by("id", "asc");
            //if ($rows > 0) {
            //  $this->db->limit($rows, $limit_from);
            //}
            $query = $this->db->get();      
            $query_result = $query->result();
            return $query_result;
        }
```

View searchmalegender.php

```
     <?php echo form_open_multipart("admin/searchmaleconfirm");?>

                  <div class="form-group">
                   <span id="provincedropdown"></span>

                      </div><!-- /.form-group -->


                      <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="submit">Search</button>
                      </div>
                      </form>
```

view maleresult.php

```
    <?php $sessiondata = $this->session->all_userdata();?>
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                      <h3 class="box-title">Free Members</h3>
                    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                      <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th><center>Sr#</th>
                            <th><center>Full Name</th>


                            <th><center>Mobile Number</th>
                              <th><center>Membership# / CNIC</th>
                            <th><center>Email Address</th>
                            <th><center>Date of Birth</th>
                            <th><center>Province</th>
                            <th><center>District</th>
                            <th><center>Tehsil</th>
                            <th><center>Union Council</th>
                            <th><center>Silsalah</th>
                            <th><center>Block</th>
                            <th><center>Ward</th>
                            <th><center>Polling Station</th>
                            <th><center>Registered</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php $sr=0;?>
                          <?php foreach ($freemembers as $member): ?>
    <tr><td><center><?php echo $sr+=1; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->first_name; ?></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $member->mobile; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->cnic; ?></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $member->email; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->dob; ?></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $member->province; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->district; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->tehsil; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->uc; ?></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $member->silsalano; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->blockcode; ?></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $member->wardno; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->pollingstation; ?></td><td><center><?php echo $member->created; ?></td>
    <?php /*?><?php if($sessiondata['data_modification']):?><?php */?>
    <?php if($sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir'):?>
    <td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/deletefreemember/" . $member->id; ?>">delete</a></td>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php /*?>    <?php if($sessiondata['data_modification'] || $sessiondata['username'] == 'irfan' || $sessiondata['username'] == 'kashif'):?><?php */?>
    <?php if($sessiondata['username'] != 'bilal.sabir'):?>

    <td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/printcardfree/" . $member->id; ?>">print</a></td>

    <td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/editprofilefree/" . $member->id; ?>">edit</a></td>
    <td><center><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/admin/changepasswordfree/" . $member->id; ?>">change pwd</a></td>
    <?php endif;?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                  </div><!-- /.box -->


                </div><!-- /.col -->
              </div><!-- /.row -->
            </section><!-- /.content -->
          </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Model.php`, change `WHERE` clause to any of the following:

```
$this->db->where('gender = male');
```

OR

```
$this->db->where('gender = ',  'male');
```

OR

```
$this->db->where('gender', 'male');
```

OR

```
$this->db->where(array('gender', 'male') );
```

Comment: $this->db->where('gender', 'male'); is the right answer sir!! thankyou very much.. you are love

Answer (score 0):

you should fix this:

```
 $this->db->where('gender','male');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help :)

Try this code:

`$this->db->where('gender', 'male');`

or

`$this->db->where('gender =', 'male');`

You can refer to this documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

-KD

Comment: $this->db->where('gender', 'male'); is the answer!! thankyou very much sir!!